# DSpace 7.3 UI Update - Refused to apply style from 'dspace-theme.css' because its MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: css, angular, dspace

Upgrading UI from DSpace 7.2 to 7.3, the CSS is not loading on home page. I get this error on console:
[Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost/dspace-theme.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO89E.png)

Running on a Virtual Box, under Rocky Linux 8.5.

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/1mSOSe8.png) is the full Chrome Console ouput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that the file dspace-theme.css was missing. I tried copying it to the supposed location ([dspace-source]/dist/browser/dspace-theme.css) with no success.

Finally, I ended up downloading and building the UI source code again on another folder, and now it works.